# How to skip the line if meet the delimiter?

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I am writing a parameter input program, it reads the file that originally used for FORTRAN. Some lines have the fortran annotation starts with '!'. I use std::getline to read file line by line. My question is how to parse the line such that it only keeps the string before '!' and discard the left?
Thank you very much!

Comment: After you have your whole line, construct a string stream _e.g. `istringstream iss(line);` and use getline again. Perhaps something like `string code; if (getline(iss, code, '!') && iss.good()) getline(iss, code);` -- this will either return the entire line as is, or if it encounters '!' it'll return everything that follows. Apparently this is what you're asking when you say "discard the left". If you want to keep only the left (also apparent when you say "keep string before"), it's even simpler: `getline(iss, code, '!');` -- there's some confusion here where you say two different things.

Comment: @paddy I didn't consider _discard the left_ as ambiguous (I read it as: "discard the rest") until I read your comment as well. ;-) OP stated as well _it only keeps the string before '!'_

Answer (score 2):

You may take advantage of the good fitting design of the `std::string`s functions
`rfind` and `substr`.

Please read [std::string::rfind()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) and [std::string::substr()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

The `substr` function will interprete the potential result `npos` of the `rfind` function in a favourable way for this task.

And then you can use the simple statement:

```
line.substr(0,line.rfind('!'))
```

And with that, an example code could look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream stream{R"(Line1
Line2!
Line3!xxx
!
!yyy)"};

int main() {
    
    std::string line{};
    
    while(std::getline(stream, line)) {
        
        std::cout << line.substr(0,line.rfind('!')) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

[**Life Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8c0016c7b4b2b24)